# Navigation inside NSURLSession "completion handler" Not Work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I have a tap gesture to submit data:

```
- (void)tapSubmitDataRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if (_userNameOrEmailTextField.text != NULL) {

    // NSURLSession
    NSString *dataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost:8080/api/users/%@", _userNameOrEmailTextField.text];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (data != nil) {
            // Convert the returned data into a dictionary.
            NSError *error;
            NSMutableDictionary *returnedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                // If no error occurs, check the HTTP status code.
                NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
                // If it's other than 200, then show it on the console.
                if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
                    NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %ld", (long)HTTPStatusCode);
                }

                passwordStoredInDatabase = [returnedDict valueForKey:@"password"];

                if ([passwordStoredInDatabase isEqualToString:[self createSHA512:self.passwordTextField.text]]) {

                    NSLog(@"Passwords Match!");

                    UIViewController *demoIntro = [[DemoIntroViewController alloc] init];
                    demoIntro = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoIntroViewController"];
                    [self.navigationController showViewController:demoIntro sender:self];

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Passwords Not Match!");
                }
            }
        }
    }] resume];

    /**UIViewController *demoIntro = [[DemoIntroViewController alloc] init];
    demoIntro = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoIntroViewController"];
    [self.navigationController showViewController:demoIntro sender:self];*/
}
}
```

**Everything works well except the navigation part if that part is put inside the completion handler.**

Please notice:

1) The passwords match.

2) The navigation part works well outside the completion handler.

I need to put the navigation part inside because I need to have access to the NSString "passwordStoredInDatabase".

However, if ask from outside the completion handler, "passwordStoredInDatabase" is null.

**If you can help me solve either one of the problems:**

1) How can I make the navigation part work inside the completion handler?

2) How can I have access to NSString "passwordStoredInDatabase" from outside, which is generated inside the completion handler? It's currently null outside, but not null inside. The variable is declared in the "implementation" block at the very beginning as follows.

```
@implementation LoginViewController {
    UITextField *activeTextField;
    NSString *passwordStoredInDatabase;
}
```

After printing some debug msgs, the problem with accessibility seems to be the order of execution. How can I make sure the code outside the NSURLSession part executes after the NSURLSession part completes? I have tried

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            completionHandler(data);
        }];
```

to wrap the NSURLSession part. But it still didn't work.

Comment: Always perform UI updates on the main queue.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right. It works now!

Answer (score 2):

Even though the issue with UI update is resolved, I am not in favor of your code design - which can cause bigger issues. Try to make leverage of object-oriented programming (OOP) techniques.

1) Abstraction. Keep your network layer and views agnostic of each other. I would suggest to look into MVVM design pattern.  Avoid to do everything in one view controller. But here's an example if you want to make a network call, and navigate after receiving the response.

2) There may be multiple approaches, such as NSNotifications, delegate pattern etc. This is a very basic completion block that would help you with an optimal design -

```
-(void)initializeLoginFlow:(void (^)(BOOL loginStatus, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    __block NSError *error;
    __block BOOL success;

    // Make a network request using NSURLSession
    // Parse the response and update success object.
    // Make sure to add weakSelf and use strongSelf inside the block.

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(success, error);
    }
}

- (void)tapSubmitDataRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [self initializeLoginFlow:^(BOOL loginState, NSError *error) {
        if (loginState) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Navigation. Passwords matched.
            });
        }
    }];
}
```